# Unable to Share NSURL and NSString simultaneously to iMessage app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller, imessage

Is it possible to share `NSURL` and `NString` at the same time using the `UIActivityViewController`?
I know it's possible using the `MFMessageComposeViewController` but wanted to use the native UI sheet so the user can select a different app if they wanted.

In this example, the filePath variable is a path to a video file saved on the device.

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray new];
[items addObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
UIViewController *rootViewController = UnityGetGLViewController();
UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
[rootViewController presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Updating the items with an additional string value will result in only the video being shared.

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray new];
[items addObject:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
[items addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Check out this video!"]];
UIViewController *rootViewController = UnityGetGLViewController();
UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
[rootViewController presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The "Check out this video!" text is never included in the iMessage app.

Is this something that is possible? If not It would be nice to see some official Apple documentation about this. Also, this would be quite surprising considering iMessage is a built-in app, you would imagine it would have this capability.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. In my own app, if I pass an array with a file NSURL for a local video (a .mov file originally selected from the photo library) and the same string shown in your question, then when the activity view appears, selecting Messages results in the New Message screen appearing and the message contains the text followed by the video. Selecting Mail also shows a new email screen with the text and the video both in place in the message body. I tested this with an Objective-C app on a real iPhone 13 Pro running iOS 16.4.1.

Comment: @HangarRash Interesting, I tested it on a real iPhone 12 iOS 15.6.1 using an mp4 file downloaded into the app data. There are several differences in our test cases, I could try using the same conditions as you. Also, it would be great if you could post a snippet of the code so we could compare that as well, thanks.

Comment: I essentially used your code. I just created the `NSURL` from my own file path to a .mov file stored within the app's sandbox. The key difference seems to be iOS 15.6.1 vs 16.4.1. I can't imagine the mp4 vs mov makes any difference.

Comment: @HangarRash That was it, updated my phone to iOS 16.4.1, and now it works. I guess on 15.6.1 there was a bug with the `UIActivityViewController`. You can write an answer with this information and I can mark it as resolved. Or I can, either way works for me(If we consider this resolved, still technically a problem for users under 16). But thanks though.

Comment: I'd rather not post an answer since all we know at this point is that it didn't work under iOS 15.6.1 and it works with 16.4.1. I have no way to check if it worked on any other versions before 15.6.1 or any other 16.x versions.